# How to force run antivirus at boot time if a persistent virus present?

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware, anti-virus, rootkit

[Recently](https://superuser.com/questions/1443904/scanners-cannot-find-a-virus-are-there-alternative-scanning-technologies) i get a virus, undetectable with virus scanners in offline OS state. The virus doesn't let to run antiviruses, debuggers, cmd, msconfig.
Unfortunately, by backup is broken.

My idea is to force run in contaminated OS (Windows 7 x64) an antivirus or rootkit remover at system start or even before OS start to run the OS like in emulator, but i'm noob in the technologies like these.

I think this could produce better results than [ordinary scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/100360) of off-lined or online OS using different tools, because of another level of control - it's dynamic control of code execution, similar to debugging.

How and which tools|antiviruses can be run at boot of infected OS?

I did try to run with no success

- aswmbr.exe
- Autoruns.zip
- avast_free_antivirus_setup_online.exe
- avg_antivirus_free_setup.exe
- avira_en_fass0_1341776598-1558627902__ws.exe
- ComboFix.exe
- GMER.exe
- mb3-setup-37469.37469-3.7.1.2839-1.0.586-1.0.10430.exe
- mtze6570.exe
- radix_installer.zip
- SmartFix.exe
- tdsskiller.exe
- msconfig
- cmd as admin
- far as admin.

Autoruns managed to run, but nothing set as being run at system startup, as everything was let out earlier.

Please note, the question is about how to run antivirus or tool over contaminated OS without antivirus installed in it.

There are [good answers](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit), related to scanning or defending with antiviruses, but don't see solutions for unsuccessful offline scan with virus actively preventing antivirus start.

If you consider the question is been answered, please provide your exact link to the answer with explanation.

Comment: The answer is to use a bootable antivirus, freshly downloaded. Some suggestions can be found in the link.

Comment: @harrymc please, list those you suggest to consider, if they are present

Comment: Read the link. If you don't have the patience, search for the word "boot".

Comment: @harrymc The scanners used were the latest ones, but my question is NOT about an offline scanner, but about how to force run antivirus in live infected OS. If you answer, please be specific about several solutions. "Search..", 'can be found' are not the answers.